# Make a single dropdown menu open to the right in Semantic UI

Tags: semantic-ui

The Semantic UI Dropdown documentation gives examples of dropdowns that open to the left and right. However, all of the examples given show a parent dropdown that opens downwards, with the items of that dropdown being themselves dropdown which open to the left or the right. I am trying to create a vertical menu, each element of which is a dropdown that opens to the right. The vertical menu itself should *not* be a dropdown. I have tried many combinations of arranging the `menu`, `right`, `dropdown` classes and I simply cannot get it to work. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've discovered that Semantic will do this automatically if you place your dropdowns in a vertical menu:

```
<div class="ui vertical menu">
  <div class = "ui dropdown item">
    <span class="text">Prompt</span>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    ...
```